# Creating xls for xml

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm having a hard time creating a xls transformation file for the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl"?>
<ExportedData xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Header>
    <StartDate>2015-02-02T00:00:00</StartDate>
    <EndDate>2015-03-04T23:59:00</EndDate>
    <RecordCount>4</RecordCount>
    <Client />
    <DocumentCount>0</DocumentCount>
  </Header>
  <Applicants>
    <Applicant>
      <ApplicantId>2176</ApplicantId>
      <ModuleTypeId>1</ModuleTypeId>
      <ApplicantInfo>
        <Applications>
          <Application>
            <ApplicationId>6177</ApplicationId>
            <Fields>
              <Field>
                <FieldName>Action Status</FieldName>
                <FieldText>Submitted</FieldText>
              </Field>
              <Field>
                <FieldName>BGCheck Result</FieldName>
                <FieldText />
              </Field>
              <Field>
                <FieldName>Date Hired</FieldName>
                <FieldText />
              </Field>
              <Field>
                <FieldName>Location Code</FieldName>
                <FieldText>ManNY</FieldText>
              </Field>
            </Fields>
          </Application>
        </Applications>
      </ApplicantInfo>
      <ApplicantActionDocsInfo />
      <ApplicantFormsInfo />
      <ApplicantActionsInfo />
    </Applicant>
```

Obviously there is more to the xml file (more Applicants). I have been trying to use this resource: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_transformation.asp which I understand, but when trying to apply it to my xml, it isnt quite working out. I have tried to start with something extremely simple but I'm not getting the correct output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>Applicants Info</h2>
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th>ApplicantId</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="ExportedData/Applicants/Applicant">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="ApplicantId"/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Again, this is just a simple test case that I have tried (It just shows Applicant Id). My final goal is to essentially display all information presented in the xml. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks to me as if you are trying to learn the XSLT language by looking at a few examples and extrapolating from them. That's not a good learning strategy. You will never learn the important concepts of the language (for example, how context works) by that approach. Get yourself a book and work through the introductory chapters; you will save yourself a lot of time in the end.

Comment: Also, changing your question in response to an answer is terribly confusing, because the existing answer no longer makes any sense. When appropriate, it can make sense to add information to your question, but you should never apply a correction to your code suggested by someone in an answer, or the thread becomes completely unintelligible.

Answer (score 2):

You'll get the value of `ApplicantId` when you change this

```
<xsl:for-each select="Applicants/Applicant">
```

to

```
<xsl:for-each select="//Applicants/Applicant">
```

or

```
<xsl:for-each select="ExportedData/Applicants/Applicant">
```

**or** the match pattern of your template:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
```

to

```
<xsl:template match="ExportedData">
```

Currently, your template is matching the root level of the input XML, and `Applicants` is not the first element of the input.

Comment: @John I've just tested the adjusted XSL with your input XML (adding the missing closing tags, so I only have one `Applicant`) and get the result displayed in Firefox when I load the XML. How do you compile the XML?

Answer (score 2):

```
<xsl:template match="/">
```

puts you in the context of the root (document) node. From this context,

```
<xsl:for-each select="Applicants/Applicant">
```

selects nothing, because `Applicants` is not a child of the root node. Try instead:

```
<xsl:for-each select="ExportedData/Applicants/Applicant">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to write templates instead of for-each selectors. See comments below.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <!-- match root - build html elements -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ExportedData">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Do nothing for the header -->
    <xsl:template match="Header"/>

    <!-- Build table for applicants -->
    <xsl:template match="Applicants">
        <h2>Applicants Info</h2>
        <table border="1">
            <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                <th>ApplicantId</th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- for each applicant create a table row -->
    <xsl:template match="Applicant">
        <tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- for each Applicant/ApplicantId generate table cell -->
    <xsl:template match="ApplicantId">
        <td>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </td>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- you probably will want to add more stuff to the table, use templates to do so.-->  
    <xsl:template match="ModuleTypeId | ApplicantInfo | ApplicantActionDocsInfo | ApplicantFormsInfo | ApplicantActionsInfo"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time getting the ApplicantInfo elements correct since there are multiple elements for each ApplicantId. How would I create additional rows?

Comment: Please update your question and show me how you are trying to do this.